# Update with except statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, except

This is my query

```
SELECT PageVisit_ID,TargetSite_ID FROM [A].Datawarehouse.mi.ctb_PageEvent WITH (NOLOCK)
 EXCEPT 
 SELECT PageVisit_ID ,TargetSite_ID FROM [B].Datawarehouse.mi.ctb_PageEvent WITH (NOLOCK)
```

these two tables from two servers. I need to update `targetsite_id` in `[A].Datawarehouse.mi.ctb_PageEvent` records from `[B].Datawarehouse.mi.ctb_PageEvent`
only matched with above query results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @SummaryOfChanges TABLE(Change VARCHAR(20));

MERGE INTO [A].Datawarehouse.mi.ctb_PageEvent AS Target
USING ( SELECT PageVisit_ID ,TargetSite_ID FROM [B].Datawarehouse.mi.ctb_PageEvent WITH (NOLOCK)) AS SOURCE
ON Target.TargetSite_ID = Source.TargetSite_ID 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    //UPDATE OR do nothing
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    //INSERT 
OUTPUT $action INTO @SummaryOfChanges;
```

Please refer to [SQL SERVER – Merge Operations – Insert, Update, Delete in Single Execution](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/06/08/sql-server-merge-operations-insert-update-delete-in-single-execution/). my solution just gives a basic idea on how to do this. It might not work 100% initially. Just tweak it once you understand the logic

Comment: but i need to update records only from this query result set (SELECT PageVisit_ID,TargetSite_ID FROM [A].Datawarehouse.mi.ctb_PageEvent WITH (NOLOCK)
 EXCEPT 
 SELECT PageVisit_ID ,TargetSite_ID FROM [B].Datawarehouse.mi.ctb_PageEvent WITH (NOLOCK))