# How to convert select statement to an update statement

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create an Update statement that works or functions the same as this Select statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE field1 = 1 
AND field2 NOT IN (SELECT field2 
                   FROM table 
                   WHERE field1 = 0)
```

Comment: I would try using except. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462560/update-with-except-statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The translation from `select` to `update` is very simple in this case as it doesn't require SQL Server's non standard proprietary update syntax.

```
UPDATE table 
SET    field3 = 'X' 
WHERE  field1 = 1 
       AND field2 NOT IN (SELECT field2 
                          FROM   table 
                          WHERE  field1 = 0)
```

Another way of translating it would be to just put the whole select statement inside a cte and update that.

```
WITH t 
     AS (SELECT * 
         FROM   table 
         WHERE  field1 = 1 
                AND field2 NOT IN (SELECT field2 
                                   FROM   table 
                                   WHERE  field1 = 0)) 
UPDATE t 
SET    field3 = 'Y'
```

If any of the columns involved are nullable `not exists` will likely have a better plan though.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE [Table1]
 SET [Column1] = ?
    ,[Column2] = ?
  --,...  other columns and so on....
WHERE field1 = 1 
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Table2 
                  WHERE field1 = 0
                   AND  Field2 = [Table1].Field2 )
```